# Drop down menu does not work in iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, iphone

My sample drop down menu works in IE, FIREFOX, OPERA,  but does not work in iPhone even after adjustment recommendations as provided in this link(http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly/tag/navigation)
The webpage: http://www.lipno-pocasi.cz/index2.html

**HTML**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>

    <li class='has-sub'><a href="#">Home-meteo</a>
       <ul>  
         <li class='has-sub'> <div class="menu"><a href="hl_strana.php">Úvodní stránka - meteo</a></div></li>   
         <li class='last'><div class="menu"><a href='./novinky-new.html'>Novinky a aktuality</a></div></li>   
       </ul>
    </li>   

</ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="./js/doubletaptogo.js"></script>

<script>
$( function()
   {
      $( '#cssmenu li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
   });
</script>
```

**PS:** I am a beginner. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with the device browser. They are not exactly in par with the Desktop version. I see the above link work great on all the browser FF, chrome and Safari.

A quick workaround to fix this issue. Try removing 'visibility:hidden;' from you menu2.css file for the selector '#cssmenu > ul > li > ul'. Some where at line:52.

Hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but after removing the [visibility: hidden] problem is the iPhone even as FF,Chrome, IE11 when moving the mouse to the bottom and see http://lipno-pocasi.cz/index2.php menu is completely visible unpacked in IE8. Thank you for help